# How to create setup interceptors in redux toolkit query

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

As in my old projects i used `axios` to fetch the data from server and created a common file for all axios API requests .Now i want to use `Redux toolkit query` ,how can create same common file like adding base url and for Every get request use a common function.

```
import axios from 'axios';
    const API_URL = 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1';
    
// setting the base url for axios
const axiosApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
});

export async function get(url, config = {}) {
  let res = await axiosApi.get(url, {}, { ...config });
  return res.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [`fetchBaseQuery`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

That's what `baseQuery` does. `fetchBaseQuery` already does most of what you would usually want to do. If that's not enough for you, the recommended approach is to wrap the `baseQuery` function created by calling `fetchBaseQuery(...)` in your own `baseQuery` function with the added functionality.

This is described in the docs under [Customizing Queries](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries)